# ckeditor4 - Append css class to first generated DIV on IFrame mode using ckeditor API

Tags: css, ckeditor, customization, ckeditor4.x

I am using CKEditor 4.5 in classic mode (Iframe) with sharedspace plugin.

ckeditor4 automatically create a `div` (#cke_mytextarea1) just below each `textarea` and inside that `div`, a `iframe` is created too.

The `css` for this `div` is also created automatically.

How do i append a `css` class to `div`, using ckeditor API?

I try use `contentsCss` configuration http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.config-cfg-contentsCss
but the `css` is applied on iframe and not `div`

Example:

From this code:

```
<form id="myform" method="post">
    <textarea id="mytextarea1" data-ckenable="true"></textarea>
    <textarea id="mytextarea2" data-ckenable="true"></textarea>
    <textarea id="mytextarea3" data-ckenable="true"></textarea>
</form>
```

and after i start ckeditor instances, result in this generated code:

```
<form id="myform" method="post">
    <textarea id="mytextarea1" data-ckenable="true" style="visibility: hidden; display: none;"></textarea>

    <!-- i need append css class to this ("#cke_mytextarea1") div using ckeditor API -->

    <div id="cke_mytextarea1" class="cke_1 cke cke_reset cke_chrome cke_editor_mytextarea1 cke_ltr cke_browser_webkit"
         dir="ltr" lang="pt-br" role="application" aria-labelledby="cke_mytextarea1_arialbl"><span
            id="cke_mytextarea1_arialbl" class="cke_voice_label">Editor de Rich Text, mytextarea1</span>

        <div class="cke_inner cke_reset" role="presentation">
            <div id="cke_1_contents" class="cke_contents cke_reset" role="presentation" style="height: 200px;"><span
                    id="cke_101" class="cke_voice_label">Pressione ALT+0 para ajuda</span>
                <iframe src="" frameborder="0" class="cke_wysiwyg_frame cke_reset" title="Editor de Rich Text, mytextarea1"
                        aria-describedby="cke_101" tabindex="0" allowtransparency="true"
                        style="width: 100%; height: 100%;"></iframe>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

<!-- ... -->
</form>
```

Full sample code preview here: http://jsfiddle.net/luzfcb/ymoc2r1w/2/

Same code below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <link type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css"
          rel="stylesheet">

    <link type="text/css"
          href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pace/1.0.2/themes/blue/pace-theme-loading-bar.css"
          rel="stylesheet">


    <style>
        .body {
            background: rgb(204, 204, 204);
        }

        .maindiv {
            /*
            the content is hidden by default,
            and will be shown only after
            completed page load and
            finalized ckeditor startup
            */
            display: none;
        }

        .content-section {
            margin-bottom: 100px;
        }

        article {
            background: white;
            width: 21cm;
            height: 29.7cm;
            display: block;
            margin: 0 auto 0.5cm;
            box-shadow: 0 0 0.5cm rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
            padding: 30px;
            font-size: 11pt;
            line-height: 22pt;
        }

        article form {
            height: 100%;
        }

        @media print {
            body, article[size="A4"] {
                margin: 0;
                box-shadow: 0;
                background: transparent;
            }

            .cke_pagebreak {
                display: block;
                page-break-before: always;
            }

            .content-section {
                margin-bottom: 0;
                padding-top: 0;
            }

            .no-print {
                display: none;
            }

        }


    </style>
</head>

<body class="body">

<div class="maindiv">
    <div id="top-bar" class="navbar-fixed-top no-print">
        <div id="top-ck-toolbar">
            <!-- ckeditor top toolbar is rendered here -->
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="content-section" class="content-section">
        <article>

            <form id="myform" method="post">
                <textarea id="mytextarea1" data-ckenable="true"></textarea>
                <textarea id="mytextarea2" data-ckenable="true"></textarea>
                <textarea id="mytextarea3" data-ckenable="true"></textarea>
            </form>

        </article>
    </div>

    <div id="bottom-bar" class="navbar-fixed-bottom no-print">
        <div id="bottom-ck-toolbar">
            <!-- ckeditor bottom toolbar is rendered here -->
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pace/1.0.2/pace.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdn.ckeditor.com/4.5.2/full-all/ckeditor.js"></script>

<script>

    //get the id's of elements that contains "data-ckenable" attribute
    function get_ckenable_element_ids() {
        return $("[data-ckenable]").map(function () {
            return this.id;
        }).get();
    }

    var ckenable_element_ids_list = get_ckenable_element_ids();

    var ckeditor_config = {
        extraPlugins: [
            "sharedspace",

        ].join(),
        sharedSpaces: {
            top: "top-ck-toolbar",
            bottom: "bottom-ck-toolbar"
        }
    };

    //start ckeditor
    ckenable_element_ids_list.map(function (id_element) {
        CKEDITOR.replace(id_element, ckeditor_config);
    });


    function fix_content_padding() {
        var top_menu = $('#top-ck-toolbar');
        var content_div = $('#content-section');
        var current_top_menu_height = parseInt(top_menu.css('height').replace(/[^-\d\.]/g, ''));
        var new_padding_value_to_content = "".concat(current_top_menu_height + 130).concat("px");
        content_div.css('padding-top', new_padding_value_to_content);
        console.log("fixxxx: ", new_padding_value_to_content);
    }

    window.addEventListener('resize.fix_content_padding', fix_content_padding, false);

    var paceOptions = {
        "ajax": false,
        "restartOnRequestAfter": false,
        "document": false
    };

    window.paceOptions = paceOptions;
    Pace.on('hide', function () {

        $(".maindiv").fadeIn("fast");
        fix_content_padding();
    });

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'm afraid that your question is a bit too complex. Too many things happen in the code that you pasted and there's no relation to the question that you asked. Please try to reformat your question.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using it with Django or directly as JS component?
Because I use CKEditor with Django (**django-ckeditor==4.5.1**) and it's working very well.

Ping me if your case is using Django and I could give more details how it's working so far.